# Using Jupyter behind a proxy

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, conda

Is there a similar config to that of .condarc (anaconda 4.0.0) that allows Jupyter to be configured to work behind a corporate proxy on a local machine?

Error received:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required
```

Comment: I fixed this by setting the `HTTPS_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables, _correctly_. My HTTPS one was incorrect, and failing similarly.

Answer (score 26):

Way easier: Just add the following to your notebook:

```
In [1]: import os
        os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://user:passwd@host:port" 
        os.environ['https_proxy'] = "https://user:passwd@host:port"
```

after that, requests will work [OK=200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), e.g.

```
In [2]: import requests
        requests.get("https://google.com")
Out[2]: <Response [200]>
```

Comment: Easier, but kind of cumbersome: You would have to repeat in every single notebook you create + You don't want these lines to appear in your notebook if you publish it

Comment: Feel free to concatenate strings from environment variables or config files that hold your password.

Comment: was setting my proxy settings in the `.condarc` file, which allowed me to work with conda behind my company proxy. However, any request done via a JN (installed in a conda env) was not working. Adding this to my script solved the issue. Not sure why JN is not taking the proxy settings of the `.condarc` file but in any case this is solving my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Based on [this link](https://www.jayakumar.org/linux/how-to-configure-httphttps-proxy-for-ipython-notebook-server/).

You have to modify the Jupyter notebook server env. Create a file named `00-something.py` under your Jupyter notebook server profile and add the following:

For example:

```
vi /.jupyter/profile_myserver/startup/00-startup.py
```

(or on Windows open up "C:/Users/*your username*/.jupyter/profile_myserver/startup/00-startup.py" in your editor of choice)

and add

```
import sys,os,os.path
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY']="http://proxy.example.com:80"
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY']="https://proxy.example.com:443"
```

you can confirm the env variables by running

```
%env
```

in a cell and the output

```
{'CLICOLOR': '1',
'GIT_PAGER': 'cat',
'HOME': '/home/jay',
'HTTP_PROXY': 'http://proxy.example.com:80',
..
```

Next try

```
import requests
requests.get("http://google.com")
```

If you get a response [200] then you are all set.

Comment: What would be the procedure on Windows 7?

Comment: Not sure but I would expect the only difference is where you find the server profile and possibly what you edit it with.

Comment: the 's' letter is missing in the address for the https?

Comment: I added `00-startup.py` with the above contents in `C:\Users\my_username\.ipython\profile_default\startup` folder. Issue fixed

Comment: What should I do if I use a socks5 proxy? Thanks!

Comment: This solution did not quite work for me. I needed to add the file to the path described by Arjun Mathew Dan: C:\Users\my_username\.ipython\profile_default\startup

Answer (score 2):

Use the lowercase variable instead, it works for me:

```
import sys,os,os.path
os.environ['http_proxy']="http://user:passwd@host:port"
os.environ['https_proxy']="http://user:passwd@host:port"
```

Then check your env variable using this:

```
%env
```

The output will be like this:

```
{'CLICOLOR': '1',
 '...'
 '...'
 'http_proxy': 'http://gunawan.marbun:xxxxxxxx@cache.itb.ac.id:8080'
 'https_proxy': 'https://gunawan.marbun:xxxxxxxx@cache.itb.ac.id:8080'
 'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1'}
```

Notes: Since I can't comment due to my reputation (req 50 and I'm newbie), I present new answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution for me was to add an exception to my proxy configuration. I just put the address `http://localhost:8888` to my exception list and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Based on these [Jupyter customization instructions](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#since-jupyter-does-not-have-profiles-how-do-i-customize-it):

1. Create the directory `.jupyter_config` in your home directory
2. Add the line `JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR=~/.jupyter_config` to your bash/shell  profile (eg. `.bash_profile`).
3. Add a script titled `startup.py` to `~/.jupyter_config` with the following code, customized with your specific proxy information:

```py
import os
os.environ['http_proxy']= "http://user:passwd@host:port"
os.environ['https_proxy']= "https://user:passwd@host:port"
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY']= os.environ['http_proxy']
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY']= os.environ['https_proxy']
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Ensure you are connected to VPN to office network**

**2. You can set up proxy before starting notebook or in every notebook**

**A. before starting**

from jupyer notebok, start terminal  (From option New on right top)

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://fakeserver:fakeport
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://fakeserver:fakeport

jupyter notebook
```

(This will start notebook in new terminal, with proxy set that can be checked with %env)

**B. in every notebook**

```
import sys,os,os.path
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY']="http://fakeserver:fakeport"
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY']="http://fakeserver:fakeport"
```

**3. in windows, set the environmental variables**

```
This PC (Rt Click) >> propertis>> Advanced System Setting >> Advanced >> Envioronmental variables>> click NEW to add 2 variables pointing HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY to "http://fakeserver:fakeport"
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who may need a socks5 proxy, the following did the trick for me:

```
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "socks5h://host:port"
os.environ['https_proxy'] = "socks5h://host:port"
```

The only difference with the http proxy was the **socks5h** part in the url. In my case the proxy didn't have username and password but I suppose these too may be added to the url like `socks5h://user:passwd@host:port`.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the problem comes due to adding `HTTPS` in the proxy server URL. For both `HTTP` and `HTTPS`, the proxy server URL should be `"http://"` only

```
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://username:complexpassword!@34@serverIP:port" 
os.environ['https_proxy'] = "http://username:complexpassword!@34@serverIP:port"



import requests
requests.get("https://google.com")
```

Response should be `200`  `OK`

If you are in a Windows domain and use `domain\username` for authentication, just use username instead of `domain\username` in python setting above